# AsyncTask doInBackground() is returning null

Tags: java, android-asynctask, youtube-data-api, google-client

I'm trying to use the `YouTube Data API`. They created a Java client. [Here is the sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#examples) that  I tried to follow to send a request to their servers. I can't have this

```
// Call the API and print results.
SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();
List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
```

in the main thread because Android doesn't allow networking on the main thread. So I tried to use the `AsyncTask`

```
public class youtubeSearchTask extends AsyncTask<YouTube.Search.List, Void, SearchListResponse> {

    @Override
    protected SearchListResponse doInBackground(YouTube.Search.List... params) {
        SearchListResponse a;
        try {
            a = params[0].execute();
        } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        return a;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(SearchListResponse searchResponse) {
        List<SearchResult> searchResultList = searchResponse.getItems();
        List<String> videoIds = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (searchResultList != null) {

            // Merge video IDs
            for (SearchResult searchResult : searchResultList) {
                videoIds.add(searchResult.getId().getVideoId());
            }
            Joiner stringJoiner = Joiner.on(',');
            String videoId = stringJoiner.join(videoIds);

            // Call the YouTube Data API's youtube.videos.list method to
            // retrieve the resources that represent the specified videos.
            try {
                YouTube.Videos.List listVideosRequest = youtube.videos().list("snippet, statistics").setId(videoId);
                new videoSearchTask().execute(listVideosRequest);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I tried

```
return params[0].execute();
```

from within the `doInBackground` method but it made me account for a possible `IOException`. So I changed the code and now it's saying `variable 'a' might not have been initialized`. What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you initialize your variable a at least with a null
`SearchListResponse a = null;` it will remove the `a not initialized`